# Unable to get volley response error message in error listener

Tags: android, android-volley

This is my code for making request to api.

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.login, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error",error.getMessage());   // ****
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username",username);
            params.put("password",password);

            return params;
        }
    };
```

End this is the answer :

> E/Volley: [1477] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for

and the error part for the starred line in the code:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Not : I am **not** asking why i am getting 400 error. I am looking for a way to handle those responses.

This the corresponding error message that i want to handle for example.

```
$output["error"] =  TRUE;
$output["message"] = "Bad Request";
http_response_code(400);
echo json_encode($output);
```

if i use something like this to handle server error codes still getting same error for printing error for case 2.

```
if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Log.e("error","1");
            } else if( error instanceof ServerError) { // case 2
                Log.e("error",error.getMessage());
            } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Log.e("error","3");
            } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
                Log.e("error", "4");
            } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Log.e("error","6");
            }
```

Comment: 400 http code stays for 'Bad Request'. Probably ou miss some parameters in your request

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi actualy post method not allowed but i can't handle those errors in my code. I am looking for a way to handle those bad situations.